# Adding a Google account for calendar purposes on iOS 8.3

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

I'm trying to add a Google account for use with the native calendar app on a new iPhone with iOS 8.3.  This Google account does not have Gmail set up for it, but I am using it for Google calendar.

With another iPhone running 8.1.3, I can go to "Settings", "Mail, Contacts, Calendars", and "Add Account."  I select "Google" and see a screen like this:

[image: Add Google account on iOS 8.1.3]

I can enter my Google account information and hit next.  I get an error that says that e-mail won't work:

[image: iOS 8.1.3 Google e-mail error]

But I can hit Save anyway, and on the next feature select screen, I can turn off Mail and leave on Calendars.  At this point, I can use my Google calendars in the iOS Calendar app.

With the new phone on iOS 8.3, here is what the new Google Add Account screen looks like, apparently showing a webpage from Google:

[image: Add Google account on iOS 8.3]

Next, I get an "Accept" screen like this:

[image: iOS 8.3 Accept screen]

After clicking "Accept", I am taken to the feature select screen for the account; however, everything is grayed out:

[image: iOS 8.3 feature select screen, grayed out]

After a few seconds, it times out and sends me back to the first Add Account screen, failing to add the account, but giving no error message.

Is this a bug in iOS 8.3?  Is there a different way I need to add this no-Gmail Google account to the Calendar app?

Comment: how is it possible to have Google account without gmail  ? how do you log in to it ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 It's very possible. I have an e-mail account on my own domain, hosted by a web host. You can use any e-mail address for a google account, not just gmail.com addresses. You can log in from any Google page.

Comment: Is it a Google Apps account @BenMiller?

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz This particular one I am trying is a Google account, not a Google Apps account.  However, I have added both Google accounts and Google Apps accounts on my 8.1.3 iPhone in this way.  On the 8.3 iPhone, I've only tried the Google account.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried the following on your iOS device:

```
Add Account > Other > Add CalDAV Calendar
```

Then enter your credentials:

---

```
Server: google.com
Username: Enter the email address of the associated Google account.
Password: Enter the password that is associated with the Google account from above.
Description: Purely for information. Enter a description of the account.
```

This should work when only using the Calendar on a Google Account.

Comment: This worked for me.  Thanks.  I wonder if this is something that will be fixed in a future version of iOS.

Comment: As far as I can remember adding CalDAV calendar and no mailbox has been around for past versions of iOS (~6.0 and above).

Comment: In 10.3.1 this is still a problem and this is still the solution.